# How to limit the number of query classes in CQRS?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, cqrs

I am implementing CQRS and I am a little confused on the how quickly number of queries are getting. 
I have googled it too but due to variety of flavors of CQRS I am not getting any appropriate solution. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong here? Here's my code and respective queries.

```
class User {
   public int Id { get; set; }   
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string Status { get; set; }
   public string Role { get; set; }
   // ...
}
```

And I want to find user by its username, so I have written query for it

```
abstract class Query<TResult> { }
class FindUserByStatusQuery : Query<IEnumerable<User>> {
       public string Status;
}
```

and the respective handler for it

```
interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> where TQuery : Query<TResult>
{ 
    TResult Handle(TQuery query);     
} 

class FindUserByStatusQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<FindUserByStatusQuery, IEnumerable<User>> 
{
               public IEnumerable<User> Handle(FindUsersByAcountStatusQuery query)
               {   
                   using (Entities db = new Entities()) 
                   {
                      status = query.status.ConvertToString();
                      return db.Users.Where(u =>  u.Status.Contains(status)).ToArray();
                   }
               }
}
```

Now, I want to look-up user by other fields too like by Id or by multiple fields (by both status & role). And there could be more queries like that.

My question is do I need to create separate query classes for them? Wouldn't that make number of queries quite high? How can I limit that?

Comment: What is the context of usage for this query?  will they search by status and role at the same time?

Comment: Yes they will search by both status and role. And there could be more queries like that.

Comment: As a matter of interest, are you using a web framework?

Comment: @Marco Nope .. not using a web framework. Own tailored implementation based on the requirements.

Answer (score 7):

I find the best approach is to be pragmatic - make the query fit the context of the current situation, and dont think beyond that.

You say they could query by status and role at the same time, so include both of those properties on the query object.

If you reuse the query 'somewhere else' in the domain, and it needs further search criteria, create a new query specifically for that domain problem.

Free yourself from the burden of 'limiting code' and deal with each situation separately.  Creating objects that deal with multiple domain scenarios leads to complexity, regression issues and brittle classes.

Give your types [a single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: But that would create multiple classes with most attributes getting repeated and just an addition of one only. And what about other similar cases?

Comment: Separate your concerns - a little more code is better than god objects serving multiple areas of your system.  It will make it more maintainable in the long run

Comment: I was thinking about using IQueryable in the QueryHandler and combine multiple criteria there. Would that be a viable solution?

Comment: Absolutely.  You can check for the existence of criteria and append these criteria to the IQueryable to build up your final query and then return it using ToArray()

Comment: Can i know from where u implemented CQRS pattern and how it look in general the process of handling those queries? i am using WEB API and need some good point to implement CQRS

Comment: i didnt take one article and copy it like for like.  Taking the time to understand the theory behind CQRS and applying it to the domain problem at hand yields the best results.  If you are specifically interested in Commands, Queries and Handlers you could read the following articles, although they dont specifically talk about CQRS itself...http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91